# How to full grow a conditional inference tree using party package

Tags: party

I am currently trying to fit a conditional inference tree using the `ctree` function in the `party` package. So far I see that some of the arguments that control the depth of the tree include `mincriterion`, `minsplit`, and `minbucket`. My goal is to try and create a fully grown tree so that each terminal node has 100% classification (I understand that this means that the tree would be rather large). However even when changing these parameters, e.g. `minsplit = 0, minbucket = 0, mincriterion = 0`, I still do not get a full grown tree. Some of the terminal nodes give me a probability of being in one class or another.

I am curious as to why this tree is not grown all the way? Are there any arguments that I am not writing in, or is it not possible for these trees to be pure at the temrinal nodes?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please try whether this problem persists with the new(er) and recommended implementation of `ctree()` in the `partykit` package? If so, please post a reproducible example and we can have a look.

Comment: Oh, and please make sure that it is possible to obtain a pure node! Consider an artificial situation with a yes/no response with only a single partitioning variable "gender" left at some node in the tree. If half of all males replied yes and the other half no - and likewise for women, then: (a) The split in gender should not be carried out as it does not improve the model. (b) Even if it were performed, both child nodes would still not be pure.